# Why the Grid Element Not Arranging The Typography

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**i want to create a component which will have books in the responsive tabs but and I used material UI  grid toh arrange them as per the screen Width , but I Dont Know what is did Wrong they should be arranged in 2 columns  below is the code and Screen shot of my result **

```
  import React from 'react'
    import { Grid, Typography, Box, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core"
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        container: {
            width: "100%",
            border: "2px solid green",
            "& > *": {
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        },
        names: {
            display: "flex"
        }
    })
    function Books() {
        const classes = useStyles()
        return (
            <Box className={classes.container}>
                <Grid item lg={6}>
                    <Typography className={classes.names}>HEllo</Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.names}>HEllo</Typography>
    
                </Grid>
            </Box>
        )
    }
    
    export default Books
```

**the view of the component**
[image]

**I want them to arrange in 2 columns **

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of the same on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-dw9tu?file=/index.js).

Here's the code.

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, Typography, Box, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    border: "2px solid green",
    "& > *": {
      textAlign: "center"
    }
  },
  names: {
    display: "flex"
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box className={classes.container}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Typography className={classes.names}>HEllo</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Typography className={classes.names}>HEllo</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```